# refresh state on going to previous scene in react native from native (android) activity after pressing back button

Tags: android, react-native, authentication, page-refresh

I am new to react native and I want to know what is the ideal way handle such situations. Here is the situation:
I have say 4 screens

```
(Native)A, (React-Native)B, (React-Native)C, (Native)D
```

my app has login options for the user from all 4 screens.

now the user navigates from **A to B to C to D**. Now he decides to login and then he goes back to **scree C** (which is react native), Now the problem is how to show new state of **screen C** ( user logged in state) and similarly of **B** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume you want to communicate between native and javascript, check out this [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#sending-events-to-javascript)